# What if the tallest height is considered the most beautiful?

Tags: truth, aesthetics

What if some people defined the tallest height is considered the most beautiful?

Some philosopher claimed that the most beautiful human doesn't exist.

Can there be any "most beautiful" human?

Comment: What philosopher? Do you have reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can in theory be a "most beautiful" human if you are willing to define what that means, e.g. if every living human between the ages of 10 and 80 on January 1st, 2015 judges the runner-up 99 most attractive humans and the candidate for most beautiful human by ranking them all from 1 to 100; then the most beautiful human is that human which has the lowest summed rank over all judges.

Given this framework, you have two possibilities:

1. There exists a unique set of features that results in the lowest (best) score.
2. There exists many sets of features that, when chosen appropriately, tie for the lowest score.

If the former, there exists a most beautiful possible human; any change to that human would result in a lower score.  If the latter, there is a class of most beautiful humans because any change diminishes beauty in the eyes of some exactly to the same extent that it raises beauty in the eyes of an equal number of others.